# In Matthew 7:6, who are the "dogs"?

Tags: matthew, metaphor

Matthew 7:6 NASB95

> Do not give what is holy to dogs, and do not throw your pearls before swine, or they will trample them under their feet, and turn and tear you to pieces.

Comment: For the immediately context the people out of the church/religion in general ie the non Jews. Matt 7. 27-28

Comment: Are you sure the term isn't referring *specifically* to the Judeans?

Comment: It is a general proverb, but perhaps to the Judeans, it must be commonly used for gentiles, as Jesus used for a woman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt 7:6a is written in quintessential Hebrew parallelism:

> Do not give that which is holy to the dogs,
>
> nor cast your pearls before the pigs,
>
> lest they shall trample upon them with their feet, and having turned,
> tear you to pieces.

Note that "give" is parallel to "cast"; "holy" is parallel to "pearls"; and "dogs" is parallel to "pigs".  Both were unclean animals and fed scraps and rubbish.  Further, "unclean" meant "unholy".  Hence Jesus essentially utters an aphorism in two lines of Hebrew parallelism.

Ellicott makes the obvious comments:

> (6) **That which is holy**.—The words point to the flesh which has been
> offered for sacrifice, the “holy thing” of Leviticus 22:6-7; Leviticus
> 22:10; Leviticus 22:16, of which no un clean person or stranger, and à
> fortiori no unclean beast, was to eat. To give that holy flesh to dogs
> would have seemed to the devout Israelite the greatest of all
> profanations. Our Lord teaches us that there is a like risk of
> desecration in dealing with the yet holier treasure of divine truth.
> Another aspect of the same warning is brought out in the second
> clause. The fashion of the time had made pearls the costliest of all
> jewels, as in the parable of Matthew 13:45 (comp. also 1Timothy 2:9),
> and so they too became symbols of the preciousness of truth. The
> “dogs” and the “swine,” in their turn, represent distinct forms of
> evil, the former being here, as in Philippians 3:2, Revelation 22:15,
> the type of impurity, the latter (as in Psalm 80:13) of ferocity.

Thus, both "dogs" and "pigs" represent that which is unholy, unclean and undeserving - in this context, people who refuse the gospel message.  This is confirmed by Jesus' use of a metaphor of pearls representing gospel truth, Matt 13:45, 46. [The great harlot wears costly pearls - a symbol in this case of a false gospel. Rev 17:4 see also Rev 18:15.]

Comment: I'm reminded of:  

[Rev 22:15 NASB95] [15] Outside are the dogs and the sorcerers and the immoral persons and the murderers and the idolaters, and everyone who loves and practices lying.

Comment: I think that the Judeans at times referred to the gentiles as the dogs, making this a bit ironic.